# Divide each data.frame inside of a list by another data.frame

Tags: r, list, dataframe, division

I have got a list of 1000 data.frames and I need to divide each of them by a 'single' data.frame.

The point is that each observation in the data.frames (contained in the list) has specific IDs which have to match with the 'single' data.frame ones and the IDs not contained into the latter have to be ignored (because no division is possible).

Here an example of one of my data.frames contained in the list:

```
df = read.table(text = 'ID   Num
                        D     34
                        W     45
                        Q     12
                        Y     45
                        B     11
                        O      2', header = TRUE)
```

The 'single' data.frame is the following:

```
sing_df = read.table(text = 'ID  Num
                              D   14
                              Q   11
                              B    9', header = TRUE)
```

By dividing `df` by `sing_df`my output should be:

```
ID   Num
D    2.428
Q    1.09
B    1.22
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can `merge` the datasets by 'ID' and create the 'Num' by dividing the 'Num.x' with 'Num.y'.

```
transform(merge(df, sing_df, by = "ID"), Num = Num.x/Num.y)[-(2:3)]
#  ID      Num
#1  B 1.222222
#2  D 2.428571
#3  Q 1.090909
```

---

In case we need some packages, then `inner_join` from `dplyr` can be helpful

```
library(dplyr)
inner_join(df, sing_df, by = "ID") %>%
        mutate(Num = Num.x/Num.y) %>%
        select(-Num.x, -Num.y)
```

---

As the OP mentioned about 1000s of datasets, it is better to keep it in a `list`, loop through the `list` elements and apply the same step as above

```
lst1 <- lapply(lst, function(dat) transform(merge(dat, sing_df, by = "ID"), 
             Num = Num.x/Num.y)[-(2:3)])
```